# Adding Relations to Laravel Factory Model

Tags: php, laravel-5, relationship, factory

I'm trying to add a relation to a factory model to do some database seeding as follows - note I'm trying to add 2 posts to each user

```
public function run()
{
   factory(App\User::class, 50)->create()->each(function($u) {
         $u->posts()->save(factory(App\Post::class, 2)->make());
   });
}
```

But its throwing the following error

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::s  
ave() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, instance 
of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given
```

I think its something to do with saving a collection. If re-write the code by calling each factory model for the post separately it seems to work. Obviously this isn't very elegant because if I want to persist 10 or post to each user then I'm having to decalare 10 or lines unless I use some kind of for loop.

```
public function run()
{
   factory(App\User::class, 50)->create()->each(function($u) {
     $u->posts()->save(factory(App\Post::class)->make());
     $u->posts()->save(factory(App\Post::class)->make());
   });
}
```

*** UPDATED ***

Is there any way to nest the model factory a 3rd level deep?

```
public function run()
{
   factory(App\User::class, 50)
       ->create()
       ->each(function($u) {
           $u->posts()->saveMany(factory(App\Post::class, 2)
                    ->make()
                    ->each(function($p){
                          $p->comments()->save(factory(App\Comment::class)->make());
          }));
   });
}
```

Comment: Models have a saveMany() method that accepts Collection objects. Try `$u->posts()->saveMany(factory(App\Post::class, 2)->make());`. However, bear in mind this will still generate 2 save queries in the background, it will not persist with one query.

Comment: @Yasen: The saveMany() method works. Is there any way to nest the model factory a 3rd level deeper? See updated post as to what I mean.

Comment: Have you found a solution of more than 2 levels nesting?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing

Answer (score 21):

Since Laravel 5.6 there is a callback functions [afterCreating & afterMaking](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database-testing#factory-callbacks) allowing you to add relations directly after creation/make:

```
$factory->afterCreating(App\User::class, function ($user, $faker) {
    $user->saveMany(factory(App\Post::class, 10)->make());
});

$factory->afterMaking(App\Post::class, function ($post, $faker) {
    $post->save(factory(App\Comment::class)->make());
});
```

Now

```
factory(App\User::class, 50)->create()
```

will give you 50 users with each having 10 posts and each post has one comment.

Answer (score 13):

Try this. It worked for me:

```
factory(\App\Models\Auth\User::class, 300)->create()->each(function ($s) {
                    $s->spots()->saveMany(factory(\App\Models\Spots\Parking::class, 2)->create()->each(function ($u) {
                            $u->pricing()->save(factory(\App\Models\Payment\Pricing::class)->make());
                    }));
                    $s->info()->save(factory(\App\Models\User\Data::class)->make());
            });
```

Comment: How would you pass on data? Like the id's that need to match? Thanks

Comment: Its a factory, notice the loops. Everything in a loop will be linked to the model.

Answer (score 8):

For a 3rd level nested relationship, if you want to create the data with the proper corresponding foreign keys, you can loop through all the results from creating the posts, like so:

```
factory(App\User::class, 50)->create()->each(function($u) {
    $u->posts()
        ->saveMany( factory(App\Post::class, 2)->make() )
        ->each(function($p){
            $p->comments()->save(factory(App\Comment::class)->make());
        });
});
```

Comment: Solved for me, and I've been googling around for half an hour trying to find something convincing.

Answer (score 6):

To answer the initial problem / error message:

The problem indeed has to do with saving the data. Your code:

```
$u->posts()->save(factory(App\Post::class, 2)->make());
```

... should be changed to

```
$u->posts()->saveMany(factory(App\Post::class, 2)->make());
```

From the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database-testing#relationships):

> You may use the createMany method to create multiple related models:
>
> $user->posts()->createMany(
>       factory(App\Post::class, 3)->make()->toArray()
>   );

**That means:**

- when only creating one model with the factory, you should use save() or create()
- when creating multiple models with the factory, you should use saveMany() or createMany()

Answer (score 2):

```
$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
return [
    'name' => $faker->name,
    'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
    'email_verified_at' => now(),
    'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // 
password
    'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
];
});

$factory->define(Post::class, function ($faker) use ($factory) {
return [
    'title' => $faker->sentence(3),
    'content' => $faker->paragraph(5),
    'user_id' => User::pluck('id')[$faker->numberBetween(1,User::count()-1)]
];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Let me, explain How to add multi level of relationship of call factory in Laravel 9 By concept of new school and old school.**
The new school is:

```
 \App\Models\Author::factory()
        ->has(
            \App\Models\Article::factory(1)
                ->has(
                    \App\Models\Comment::factory(9)
                        ->has(
                            \App\Models\Reply::factory(2)
                        )

                ))->create();`enter code here`
```

**That's for Laravel 9 . There's anthor way call Magic method. let me explain that:**

```
 \App\Models\Author::factory()->hasArticles(1)->hasComments(9)->hasReplies(2)->create();
```

this `hasArticles()` is the name of method of relationship in parent model should  convert the name with has. for example: `comments()` convert to `hasComments()`.

Now lets explain old school that's still prefect in some cases and still works good with Laravel 9.

```
        \App\Models\Author::factory(1)->create()
        ->each(function($a) {
            $a->articles()->saveMany( \App\Models\Article::factory(2)->create() )
            ->each(function($p){
                $p->comments()->saveMany(\App\Models\Comment::factory(5))->create()
                    ->each(function($r){
                    $r->replies()->saveMany(\App\Models\Reply::factory(5))->create();
                });
            });
    });
```

of course you can replace method `saveMany()` by `save()` as your relationship you have.
also you can replace method `create()` by `make()` if you want to doesn't save in database for test purposes.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

In version laravel 9, use like this

````
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\Post>
 */
class PostFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'user_id' => User::factory(),
            'title' => fake()->paragraph()
        ];
    }
}```
````