# Laravel Seeding - How to share a foreign key to child

Tags: php, laravel, relation, seeding

I want to share `user_id` to the `Payment` factory. I need it.

My `DatabaseSeeder`'s `run` function's content:

```php
\App\Models\User::factory()->count(10)->has(
    \App\Models\Client::factory()->count(30)->has(
        \App\Models\Payment::factory()->count(30)
    )
)->create();
```

How I can implement this?

Comment: I think answer is there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540845/adding-relations-to-laravel-factory-model

Comment: @Ts8060, no that's not what I want. Here are two user_id columns, in Client and in Payment. I know, that I don't need user_id in Payment because I can check the owner of the parent (Client) model, but I want to know, how I can implement this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.